# in_array is'nt finding a value

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I got an array `$data['permissions']` which looks like this: `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 11 )` and my `in_array` function I wrote do not work. Here is the code:

```
$data['permissions'] = $auth_user->getPermissions();
$stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM words;");
$stmt->execute();
while($wordsRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        echo $wordsRow['subcategory_id'];?>
                    <tr>
                        <?php
                        if($wordsRow['user_id'] == $_SESSION['user_session'] ||
                        in_array(array($wordsRow['subcategory_id']), $data['permissions'])){ ?>
                            <td><?php echo $wordsRow['name'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $wordsRow['subcategory_id'];?></td>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
```

`$wordsRow['user_id'] == $_SESSION['user_session']` in `if` works fine but `in_array` function in `if` is not finding the value that actually is in this array.

```
echo $wordsRow['subcategory_id'];
```

in while loop shows: 11 2   11. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter to [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) should be a value to find and you're passing it an array to find inside of a one-dimensional array which just isn't going to work.

Try changing this:

```
in_array(array($wordsRow['subcategory_id']), $data['permissions'])
```

To something like this:

```
in_array($wordsRow['subcategory_id'], $data['permissions'])
```

Comment: Yeah. I guess I missed that becouse of copying parts of code. Just newby. Thank you very much